# Convert nested hash with k,v to nested hash with name: k, children: [v...]

Tags: ruby, nested, data-manipulation

I have a nested ruby hash that is arbitrarily deep that has keys who's values are a hash of other keys which each have values that are hashes with other keys, which eventually gets to the end where the value of the final key is an array of hashes.

```
h = {
 foo: { 
        foo_1: { 
                 foo_1_1: [ 
                            x1: {a:1, b:2, c:2},
                            x2: {a:5, b:2, c:2}
                          ],
                 foo_2_1: [ 
                            x1: {a:1, b:2, c:2},
                            x2: {a:5, b:2, c:2}
                          ],
        foo_2: { 
                 foo_2_1: [ 
                            x1: {a:1, b:2, c:2},
                            x2: {a:5, b:2, c:2}
                          ],
                 foo_3_1: [ 
                            x1: {a:1, b:2, c:2},
                            x2: {a:5, b:2, c:2}
                          ],
        foo_3: { 
                 foo_2_1: [ 
                            x1: {a:1, b:2, c:2},
                            x2: {a:5, b:2, c:2}
                          [,
                 foo_3_1: [ 
                            x1: {a:1, b:2, c:2},
                            x2: {a:5, b:2, c:2}
                          ],
      },
 bar: { 
        bar_1: { bar_1_1: [ 
                            x1: {a:1, b:2, c:2},
                            x2: {a:5, b:2, c:2}
                          ],
        bar_2: { bar_2_1: [ 
                            x1: {a:1, b:2, c:2},
                            x2: {a:5, b:2, c:2}
                          ],
        bar_3: { bar_3_1: [ 
                            x1: {a:1, b:2, c:2},
                            x2: {a:5, b:2, c:2}
                          ],
      },
...
}
```

what I need is that hash represented as:

```
h = {
 name: foo,
 children: [
       { 
        name: foo_1,
        children: [
               { 
                 name: foo_1_1,
                 children: [ 
                            {x1: {a:1, b:2, c:2}},
                            {x2: {a:5, b:2, c:2}}
                          ]
               },
               {
                 name: foo_2_1, 
                 children: [ 
                            {x1: {a:1, b:2, c:2}},
                            {x2: {a:5, b:2, c:2}}
                          ]
               }
            ]
        },
        {
         name: foo_2,
         children: [
                { 
                 name: foo_2_1, 
                 children: [ 
                            {x1: {a:1, b:2, c:2}},
                            {x2: {a:5, b:2, c:2}}
                          ],
               },
               {
                 name: foo_3_1, 
                 children: [ 
                            {x1: {a:1, b:2, c:2}},
                            {x2: {a:5, b:2, c:2}}
                          ],
               }
            ]
        },
        {
         name: foo_3, 
         children: [
               { 
                 name: foo_2_1: 
                 children: [ 
                            {x1: {a:1, b:2, c:2}},
                            {x2: {a:5, b:2, c:2}}
                          ],
               },
               {
                 name: foo_3_1: 
                 children: [ 
                            {x1: {a:1, b:2, c:2}},
                            {x2: {a:5, b:2, c:2}}
                          ],
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
  }
...
```

Something tells me I'm missing something pretty simple.

I built the data structure using something like the following code:

```
@tree = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc)}
@valid_values = [:foo,:bar,:baz]
@combinations = @valid_values.permutation(@valid_values.length)

data_set.each do |data_hash|

  @combinations.each do |comb|
    @tree.dig(*comb.map{|k|data[k]})&.[]=(data[:x],{a:data[:a],b:data[:b]})
  end

end
```

I need to either be able to convert the resulting `@tree` hash to the other format or come up with a way to build the second structure like I need it right from the start (*preferred actually*)

edit: *modified data examples for clarity*

Also, the structure of the "leaf" nodes isn't that critical and may hold arbitrary data/structures. The key being that the parent key have the `name:` attribute and the child data have the `children:` attribute. The last data elements may be arbitrarily complex data elements but they don't have "children" so they aren't part of the original hierarchy, if that makes sense.

Comment: I suggest you modify your example so that it is a valid hash. In other words, replace each `{ ... data hash ... }` with a valid Ruby object. That serves two purposes: it clarifies your question and it gives those giving answers a way to test their code. If you do that wisely answers will provide code that works with hashes having that an arbitrarily number of nesting levels. Also, it's helpful to assign each input object to a variable (e.g., `h =  {foo: { ... }`) so that readers can refer to those variables (e.g., `h`) in comments and answers without having to define them.

Comment: Your `children` value looks like an array judging by the contents and has duplicate keys, but is surrounded by {} indicating it's a hash. Please clarify.

Also the root level object has the same issue. Looks like a hash, but has duplicate keys and should probably be an array.

Answer (score 0):

Overlooking the fact that your current input is invalid (missing closing braces), as is your current output (e.g. `foo`, `foo_1`, etc. are not defined variables).

Your desired output is not going to work. The output object will need to be converted  an `Array`, otherwise `name: :foo` will be overwritten be `name: :bar` because `Hash` keys must be unique.

If I understand correctly we can produce this Array as desired using

```
def nest(h) 
  h.map do |k,v|
    values = v.is_a?(Hash) ? nest(v) : v 
    {name: k, children: values}
  end 
end
```

with the following input:

```
h = {:foo=>
  {:foo_1=>
    {:foo_1_1=>[{:x1=>{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>2}, :x2=>{:a=>5, :b=>2, :c=>2}}],
     :foo_2_1=>[{:x1=>{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>2}, :x2=>{:a=>5, :b=>2, :c=>2}}]},
   :foo_2=>
    {:foo_2_1=>[{:x1=>{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>2}, :x2=>{:a=>5, :b=>2, :c=>2}}],
     :foo_3_1=>[{:x1=>{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>2}, :x2=>{:a=>5, :b=>2, :c=>2}}]},
   :foo_3=>
    {:foo_2_1=>[{:x1=>{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>2}, :x2=>{:a=>5, :b=>2, :c=>2}}],
     :foo_3_1=>[{:x1=>{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>2}, :x2=>{:a=>5, :b=>2, :c=>2}}]}},
 :bar=>
  {:bar_1=>
    {:bar_1_1=>[{:x1=>{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>2}, :x2=>{:a=>5, :b=>2, :c=>2}}]},
   :bar_2=>
    {:bar_2_1=>[{:x1=>{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>2}, :x2=>{:a=>5, :b=>2, :c=>2}}]},
   :bar_3=>
    {:bar_3_1=>[{:x1=>{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>2}, :x2=>{:a=>5, :b=>2, :c=>2}}]}}}
```

You will recieve the following output:

```
nest(h) 
#=> [{:name=>:foo,
#  :children=>
#   [{:name=>:foo_1,
#     :children=>
#      [{:name=>:foo_1_1,
#        :children=>[{:x1=>{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>2}, :x2=>{:a=>5, :b=>2, :c=>2}}]},
#       {:name=>:foo_2_1,
#        :children=>
#         [{:x1=>{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>2}, :x2=>{:a=>5, :b=>2, :c=>2}}]}]},
#    {:name=>:foo_2,
#     :children=>
#      [{:name=>:foo_2_1,
#        :children=>[{:x1=>{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>2}, :x2=>{:a=>5, :b=>2, :c=>2}}]},
#       {:name=>:foo_3_1,
#        :children=>
#         [{:x1=>{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>2}, :x2=>{:a=>5, :b=>2, :c=>2}}]}]},
#    {:name=>:foo_3,
#     :children=>
#      [{:name=>:foo_2_1,
#        :children=>[{:x1=>{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>2}, :x2=>{:a=>5, :b=>2, :c=>2}}]},
#      {:name=>:foo_3_1,
#        :children=>
#         [{:x1=>{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>2}, :x2=>{:a=>5, :b=>2, :c=>2}}]}]}]},
# {:name=>:bar,
#  :children=>
#   [{:name=>:bar_1,
#     :children=>
#      [{:name=>:bar_1_1,
#        :children=>
#         [{:x1=>{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>2}, :x2=>{:a=>5, :b=>2, :c=>2}}]}]},
#    {:name=>:bar_2,
#     :children=>
#      [{:name=>:bar_2_1,
#        :children=>
#         [{:x1=>{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>2}, :x2=>{:a=>5, :b=>2, :c=>2}}]}]},
#    {:name=>:bar_3,
#     :children=>
#      [{:name=>:bar_3_1,
#        :children=>
#         [{:x1=>{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>2}, :x2=>{:a=>5, :b=>2, :c=>2}}]}]}]}]
```